# Not able to convert the html tags into style in Word document

Tags: java, docx4j

I need a help to convert the html tags like ul, ol to corresponding plain text with their style preserved in java. Am able to remove the tags but failed in preserving styles.
        e.g.:

```
<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>milk</li>
    </ul>
```

to plain text with their styles like below

```
     •  Coffee
     •  Tea
     •      Milk
```

could anybody help on this ?
Thanks & Regards 
Dina

Comment: what is the effort from your side?

Comment: Make sure it is well formed XML, then see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples